# How to truncate Content Using SXA 1.6

Tags: sxa

I want to truncate content text to be for example 1 line using sitecore sxa render variant

Answer (score 6):

SXA uses Sitecore field renderers. By default, it is impossible to achieve something like that with out-of-the-box functionality.

However, there is one feature in SXA that let you do it:

1. Add `VariantTemplate` item to your variant definition (`/sitecore/templates/Foundation/Experience Accelerator/Rendering Variants/VariantTemplate`)
2. Define your template renderer and register it by adding new processor to `getVelocityTemplateRenderers` pipeline (see example processor `AddTemplateRenderers`, it registers: `NumberTool` and `DateTool`)
3. Use your tool (fill `Template` field of an item created at first step)

```powershell
<div class=introduction">
#set( $summary = $blogTool.GetSummary($item,"BlogIntroduction",200))
$summary
</div>
```

In the example above I have **blogTool** template renderer with a method GetSummary which accepts an **item**, **field name**, and a **length** to define how many characters from the field should be displayed as a blog summary.
It is up to you what is your method signature.

useful links:

- https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_accelerator/building_the_layout/renderings/create_a_rendering_variant
- https://michaellwest.blogspot.com/2017/04/custom-rendering-variant-token-tool-for-sxa.html

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways to do it. 1 with code and other with CSS.

**With CSS:**

You can use the `text-overflow:ellipis` in your CSS for it.

`div {
    white-space: nowrap; 
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}`

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp

There is a bit difference between both.

- With code, you only get the required number of text digits you enter.
- With CSS, your Text will be there but `...` will be there at the end.
- The CSS solution is good for SEO practices.

**With Code**

The solution which @alan proposed.